# Combine [paint] and [paintjob]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Weirdly, [paintjob](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paintjob) has a lot more questions than [paint](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paint), but the tags don't seem to be distinguished in a useful way.

There are questions about

- applying (or preparing to apply) paint

  - subset relating to decals' involvement when applying paint
- protection of paint
- evaluation of paint durability
- [one question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/81440/can-anybody-help-me-determine-what-this-cannondale-is-or-is-not) on identifying a bike that should really be retagged anyway.
- [one question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36951/why-are-post-80s-bike-finishes-so-dull) on the history of paint styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd pick [paint] as the root tag because it is simpler, and more accessible to ESOL.

---

Completed.

Comment: I also think this makes sense.